Gauge transformation in topological edge states in IQHE
We know that in the Landau Gauge, the tight binding hamiltonian for electrons on a square lattice in a uniform magnetic field (in $z$-direction) is
$H=-t\sum c^+_{m+1,n} c_{m,n}+c^+_{m,n+1}e^{i2\pi\phi m}c_{m,n}+h.c$
where $\phi = \frac{p}{q}$ is the magnetic field per plaquette and $t$ is the hopping parameter.
Through Peirls Subsitution, I got the total phase as
$$\theta=2\pi\frac{\phi_B}{\phi_o}$$
$$\theta^y_{m,n}=2\pi\frac{\phi_B}{\phi_o}m$$

How do I show that $\phi_B=\frac{p}{q}\phi_o$? What is the physical significance of $p$ and $q$?
How do I show that the wavefunction is $\varphi_{m,n}=e^{ik_yn}\varphi_m(k_y)$?

